# The stub received bad data. Error code 0x800706f7 when trying to run WSL on Windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install WSL on my new Windows 11 machine using command `wsl --install -d Ubuntu`, but after installation I am always getting this response: `The stub received bad data. Error code: Wsl/Service/0x800706f7`.

It is the same problem as this one https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9413, but the most common solution (using `netsh winsock reset`) doesn't work for me. I tried reinstalling WSL or using another distro, unfortunately that did not solve anything. I spend a lot of time on this issue already, but without any success.

Comment: Does this help?  It helped one person. ......  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9413

Comment: Try installing the distro from the Microsoft Store (the recommended method).

Answer (score 1):

reset the winsock with this command in powershell with **administrator** privilege.

`netsh winsock reset`